# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices using skfeature

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, tf-idf

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from skfeature.function.statistical_based import gini_index
import numpy as np

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
categories=['alt.atheism','comp.graphics','comp.os.ms-windows.misc',
        'comp.sys.ibm.pc.hardware','comp.sys.mac.hardware',
        'comp.windows.x','misc.forsale','rec.autos','rec.motorcycles',
        'rec.sport.baseball']

data_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories,
                            shuffle=True, random_state=42)

data_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test', categories=categories,
                           shuffle=True, random_state=42)
# split a training set and a test set
y_train, y_test = data_train.target, data_test.target
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(data_train.data)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(data_test.data)

feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

score = gini_index.gini_index(X_train, y_train)
ranking= gini_index.feature_ranking(score)
```

While running this code it throws me the following error:

```
....feature_extraction(20News).py", line 31, in <module>
    score = gini_index.gini_index(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\skfeature\function\statistical_based\gini_index.py", line 31, in gini_index
    left_y = y[X[:, i] <= v[j]]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: Clearly you need to figure out what `X[:, i] <= v[j]` is.  For a start review the docs for `gini_index`.  What kinds of arguments does it take?  One or the other is not the right kind.  It might be a function or method, or some `sklearn` object.

Comment: This is the documentation for the [gini_index](http://featureselection.asu.edu/html/skfeature.function.statistical_based.gini_index.html)
both are of np.shape that should be acceptable.
Its not a sklearn object that i am sure of

Comment: I"m guessing we need to see the `type`, `dtype` and `shape` for both `X_train` and `y_train`.  We can't help without knowing more about the objects that you pass this function.  The other step is to read `gini_index.py` to learn the connection between the `X` and `v` and the inputs.  I have `sklearn` installed but not `skfeature`.

Comment: This is the `shape` of `X_train=>(5790, 88059)`
This is the `shape` of `y_train=>(5790,)`
This is the `dtype`of `X_train'=>float64`
This is the `dtype` of `y_train'=>int32`
Yes i will start reading the gini_index.py if nothing else works

Comment: `X` and `y` are the 2 inputs; `v = np.unique(X[:, i])`.  The `float` character of `X` might be giving problems, since float values rarely match exactly.

Comment: But the tfidf assigns float scores... so i just modified the code a bit to use `from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer` which assigns int values rather than float but the code still throws the same error